# Getting an error stating that a declared variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am trying to create a small test application to learn to code, and I am stuck when trying to show dummy information in a mongodb database that I created.

I have tried everything I can think of, but no matter what I do it tells me that "Customer" (which is a variable that has a defined Schema) is not defined. IF it makes any difference, the database is located in a separate directory, but I assumed because I can CREATE I should be able to READ.

I apologize if anything is poorly worded or unclear, I started about a month ago from not having any programming knowledge, so I am probably trying to pick up too many things at once.

```
let express      = require("express");
let mongoose     = require("mongoose");
let bodyParser   = require("body-parser");
let app          = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/customers");

let customerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  labName: String,
  labPhone: String,
  labAddress: String,
  labBranches: String,
  labEquipment: String
});

const Customer = mongoose.model("Customer", customerSchema);

app.get("/test", function(req, res) {
  Customer.find({}, function(err, allCustomers) {
    if(err){
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.render("customer", {customers:allCustomers});
    }
  })
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000");
});
```

The expected result was to just paste the few created customers that I had in the database onto the screen just to make sure I had a valid connection to the DB, but this is the error I get.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "customer" in views directory "D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\views"
    at Function.render (D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:580:17)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\app.js:50:11
    at D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4567:16
    at D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4297:12
    at process.nextTick (D:\CRM\NeurotronicsCRM\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\completeMany.js:35:39)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

I dont understand why its referencing Customer and looking in the views directory for that. I have no problem Customer.create(); and adding dummy data.

Comment: Which exact line is throwing this error?

Comment: You're using res.render("customer") because of that line you're getting error

Comment: Use res.send({ allCustomers})

Comment: Where do I use res.send({allCustomer})?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out that in res.render the very first part of the callback should have been the page that we are loading. My mistake.